# Treat Golang defined type as the underlying one?

Tags: go, types, polymorphism

I'm new to the Go. I understand the basics of defining new types like below:

`type MyCondition bool`

I know this implies that whenever I state a function takes an instance of `MyCondition` it cannot be a `bool`, and that's great. However, I would like to treat an instance of `MyCondition` as if it was a `bool`, and I've found I can't always do that:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyCondition bool

func main() {
    var b1 MyCondition
    var b2 = true
    fmt.Println(!b1) // OK!
    fmt.Println(b1 || b1) // OK
    fmt.Println(b1 || b2)
}
```

This doesn't compile, throwing:

```
./prog.go:13:17: invalid operation: b1 || b2 (mismatched types MyCondition and bool)
```

From what I've observed, `MyCondition` works as a bool on its own, but the problem occurs when I "mix" it with an actual `bool`.

Questions are:

1. Why does this happen?
2. What's a workaround for this? I'd really like to treat it like a bool without the need of casting, polymorphically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that. You have to convert `MyCondition` to `bool` explicitly, i.e. `bool(b1) || b2`.

From [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Logical_operators):

> Logical operators apply to boolean values and yield a result of the same type as the operands.

If the left operand and the right operand have different types, the compiler can't decide the result type. So these two operands must be of the same type.

Comment: The type conversion is the key point here. It's also in the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions

Answer (score -1):

You can use aliases(pay attention to type definition) as a workaround, but in this case, you will lose guarantees of safety of types.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyCondition = bool

func main() {
    var b1 MyCondition
    var b2 = true
    fmt.Println(!b1) // OK!
    fmt.Println(b1 || b2)
    fmt.Println(foo(b2))
}

func foo(b MyCondition) bool {
    return !b
}
```

Comment: Alias and type definition are not interchangeable.